# remove git repository in the highest level keeping the lower level

Tags: git

I have a student that seems to have made a git repository on his root directory. If we remove the git from that directory will it remove the lower level repositories he put inside of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are distinct `.git` directories at the lower levels, it shouldn't kill the lower level repositories.

You should do a backup of the `.git` directory before making any changes like this though.